# flex mobile add emoticons and text

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile, emoticons, richeditabletext

I created a chat program in the mobile project, but I can not add emoticons，I know textarea can not display pictures,So I reluctantly use RichEditableText, it can add a picture, but why can not I enter characters (letters and Chinese characters) in the phone debugging, just enter only numbers, and punctuation symbols。Or there are other ways to solve add text and pictures？